# How do I create a 2D-array from calculation of a formula using two arrays as input?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, matrix

I am trying to calculate how many hours of sunlight each latitude of Earth receives every year. I have a formula which calculates this, that uses two arrays as input, the day of the year, and the latitude. What I want to do is to use the formula to create a 2D-array with each day on one axis and each latitude on another, but I am unsure how to do it since my formula will only return the dot product of the two arrays rather than the cross product, making the result only a single axis. My code looks something like this:

```
Latitude = np.linspace(1,90,90)
Days = np.linspace(1,365,365)
P = np.arcsin(0.39795 * np.cos(0.2163108 + 2 * np.arctan(0.9671396 * np.tan(0.00860 * (Days - 186)))))

daylight = 24 - (24 / np.pi) * np.arccos((np.sin(0.8333 * np.pi / 180) + np.sin(Latitude * np.pi / 180) * np.sin(P)) / (np.cos(Latitude * np.pi / 180) * np.cos(P)))
```

What I what is then to calculate the formula "daylight" but to create a resulting 2D-array such that each value of P is multiplied with each value of Latitude, creating a 90x365 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can create arrays like this:

```
a = [i for i in range(5)]
```

And you can also put multiple of these inside each other:

```
a = [[x*y for x in P] for y in Latitude]
```

And of course here you could insert your formula:

```
daylight = [[24 - (24 / np.pi) * np.arccos((np.sin(0.8333 * np.pi / 180) + np.sin(y * np.pi / 180) * np.sin(x)) / (np.cos(y * np.pi / 180) * np.cos(x))) for x in P] for y in Latitude]
```

Also this result contains a lot of `nan` values. From the context I would assume that these are polar nights/days. You could perhaps do some sort of `np.arccos(min(1,max(-1,...))` to take care of these.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot! You are correct that there will be days at the poles which have no sunlight at all, but I can set those to zero later.

Comment: Note that this uses loops in python, which are generally much slower than the inbuilt vectorized functions that numpy offers, so the solution I proposed should be faster

Answer (score 1):

Try [numpy.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). This will create two 2D-arrays for latitude and days for you:

```
lat2d, days2d = np.meshgrid(Latitude, Days)
```

Those arrays will have shape `(365, 90)` and one axis represents one variable (so in `lat2d`, all rows will be the same and in `days2d` all columns will be the same). You can then use those arrays as in your formula.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the core problem statement:

> What I what is then to calculate the formula "daylight" but to create a resulting 2D-array such that each value of P is multiplied with each value of Latitude, creating a 90x365 matrix.

Then, just do the outer product of the two arrays, from your formula,

```
_P = np.sin(P)
_Lat = np.sin(Latitude * np.pi / 180)
PLat = np.outer(_P,  _Lat)
```

`np.outer` used in this form will multiply each element of the first array (size *m*) with each element of the second (size *n*), yielding a *m x n* array.
Read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

After you've created `PLat`, the outer product matrix, add/multiply it with the other scalars.